# Select a row at view load

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to pre select a table row when the view load, however i have tried several methods, but none seem to work. At first i've set following two methods in order to define the textColor changes when a row is selected and deselected

```
open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = menuCells[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
}

open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = menuCells[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1.0)

    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(cell.menuAction, to: cell.menuTarget, from: cell, for: nil)
}
```

Then i've tried to do following things to preselect a row but it does not seem to change the textColor with alpha to 1.0

```
open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
    }
}



menuView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According Apple's documentation:

Calling **selectRowAtIndexPath** does not cause the delegate to receive a tableView(*:willSelectRowAt:) or tableView(*:didSelectRowAt:) message

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrowatindexpath

---

So in viewDidAppear method you should call manually didSelectRowAtIndexPath like in the example below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)

    myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)

    // Calling manually to the delegate method
    tableView(myTableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  }

}


// UITableView Delegate Implementation
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)

    return cell
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: not good design to call delegate methods yourself, make another method.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let iPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(iPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is part of a delegate protocol designed to handle user interactions with the `UITableView` instance. It is therefore called in response to user interaction, not programatic changes.

To resolve this, move your appearance changes into a separate function called something like `applyAppearanceSelected` and call this when you make programatic changes, and also call it from `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` to handle user-initiated changes. I would not recommend calling `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` directly yourself, because you might want to add other code there that only applies when the *user* selects a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most appropriate to select the row in the `viewWillAppear` method as the view must have been fully initialized.

The example below selects the first cell of the first section:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
    tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: selectedIndexPath)
}
```